# ClientError: GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve rendered

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs

Error while jss start:connected in sitecore jss next js sample app

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding values to parameters in `.env`, `scjssconfig.json` and `~sc102sc.dev.local\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices` has resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give it a try to debug your JSS application, you can use the [debug logging utilities provided by JSS](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/debug-logging-in-jss-apps.html). It Will help you to get more details about errors.

To resolve the error give it a try.

1. Verify that the GraphQL endpoint is correct in [package.json](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/cb32d3a21b87f488bd4bb5d311d556fd1f8354c4/samples/nextjs/package.json#L12) and the Sitecore [app definition](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/cb32d3a21b87f488bd4bb5d311d556fd1f8354c4/samples/nextjs/sitecore/config/JssNextWeb.config#L72). Try opening the GraphiQL interface in a browser, using values from your config `(<sitecore hostname + graphQL endpoint>/ui?sc_apikey=<api key>)` to make sure the endpoint is working.

Check out other Troubleshooting JSS Next.js steps [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/troubleshooting-jss-next-js-apps.html).

Hope it helps!